# Homebrew is not getting installed

Tags: homebrew

I moved from Windows to macOS a few days ago. I want to install homebrew. I used the following command

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)
```

but I am getting an error of permission denied.

```
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
/usr/local/Homebrew/.git/branches/: Permission denied
Failed during: git init -q
==> Installation successful!

==> Homebrew has enabled anonymous aggregate formulae and cask analytics.
Read the analytics documentation (and how to opt-out) here:
  https://docs.brew.sh/Analytics
No analytics data has been sent yet (or will be during this `install` run).

==> Homebrew is run entirely by unpaid volunteers. Please consider donating:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/brew#donations

error: could not lock config file .git/config: Permission denied
Failed during: git config --replace-all homebrew.analyticsmessage true
==> Next steps:
- Run `brew help` to get started
- Further documentation: 
    https://docs.brew.sh
```

I checked many other Stackoverflow answers and followed articles online but I am not getting any solution.

```
comptag:~ username$ brew install curl
-bash: /usr/local/bin/brew: No such file or directory
```

Please suggest me some solutions.

Comment: Did you install the Xcode command line tools? https://www.addictivetips.com/mac-os/install-homebrew-on-macos-catalina/ Also this is not a stack overflow question.

Comment: Yes, Xcode was installed.It was not a problem but it works now, I followed https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/5084. I was still getting Permission denied error. But again in one of the stack overflow answers, the use of SUDO was suggested in commands. I didn't understand much but it worked.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that idea too (using `sudo`). But then I'm surprised that _all_ the statements of the ruby command don't say that. I didn't have to say `sudo` when I installed brew, even on Catalina which has the most restrictive permissions. I can't figure out why you have to say it. Maybe your User is not an admin user?

Comment: Yes, I am not an admin user. That' why there are permission constraints, I guess.

Comment: It is very unusual for your main user on Mac not to be an admin user. I would suggest that you go into Users & Groups pref pane and turn your user into an admin user. Again, I repeat, this discussion should all be taking place on SuperUser or AskDifferent; there is no programming here, so this is not a StackOverflow question.

Comment: Yes, I turned into an Admin user. I was also new at the Stack Exchange community. But I just joined AskDifferent and SuperUser community. I will take care of these things now onwards.

Comment: No problem and I'm really glad you got this solved! Note that if you are on Catalina and planning to do any more stuff involving `ruby` you should almost certainly install your own up-to-date ruby; I recommend using `rbenv`. Otherwise you're going to be saying `sudo` all the time when gems are involved, which is all the time; plus the Mac ruby is out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Use the official command given on the [Homebrew website](https://brew.sh/):

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```